# is there any ulong type in Neo4j and how to make comparison

Tags: c#, neo4j, neo4jclient

I save some tweet in Neo4j with using Neo4jClient in c#. My nodes contain a property that I don't know what type it is ! I create node using a c# class and the property type in c# was ulong !
What I need is just to compare this property, something like this :

```
match n where n.StatusID = 627574605738311700 return n
```

or

```
match n where n.StatusID = '627574605738311700' return n
```

But both the queries return 0 result which is wrong , I just copy the value and it should exists !

how can I compare this kind of values?

Comment: What do you get from this query?: `MATCH n WHERE HAS(n.StatusID) RETURN n.StatusID LIMIT 1`

Comment: @cybersam I got 0 nodes for this query !!!

Comment: So, you do not have any nodes with the `StatusID` property! It seems your code for creating the nodes is not doing what you intended.

Comment: One thing to look at is: what does your code do if the attempt to create a node with a StatusID value that is too large (for a signed 64-bit integer) fails?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

neo4j [does not support](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/property-values-detailed.html) unsigned 64-bit integers.

Therefore, you should consider converting C# ulong values to strings when assigning to neo4j properties. That way, comparisons in Cypher will still work properly (as long as the value you are comparing with is also a string).

Comment: Is there any way to convert the property into string ?

Comment: Yes, you can use the [TOSTRING()](http://neo4j.com/docs/2.2.4/query-functions-scalar.html#functions-tostring) function to convert an existing property, as in `SET n.foo = TOSTRING(n.foo)`. However, in your case that does not help, since you would not have been able to create any nodes in the first place with properties that are too big. You really need to create the neo4j DB from scratch using string property values.

Comment: I don't know how but when I take one node in neo4j web interface the StatusID property is set to the correct value !!!

Comment: Fine, but you did not use the web interface to create the other nodes --the ones you are having problems with -- correct? Also, even when using the web interface, if you tried to create a node with a `StatusID` value of `18446744073709551615` (the largest `ulong` value), you should see an error.

Comment: yeah, I think you right, the ulong value are corrupted ones ! I should create from scratch ! what about double and int? (nullable int) does neo4j support this ones ?

Comment: [I already provided a link in my answer](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/property-values-detailed.html) to the acceptable property value types. Note that that page states: "NULL is not a valid property value." When you assign a NULL value to a property, neo4j will just delete that property (if it already existed) or just not add it.